# How to generate calendar in C# web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, calendar

I am referring [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609046/how-to-generate-calender-in-c-net-windows-application) and need to implement the same thing but for different data.

Can I have any code or tutorial to implement it?

I don't want to use jQuery so is it possible without jQuery / AJAX?

Comment: the day pilot lite component is free http://www.daypilot.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a built-in [Calendar control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.aspx). It could also be used with the [AJAX Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/calendar/calendar.aspx).

Comment: Darin, Heena added an edit `I don't want to use jQueary so is it possible without jQuery/AJAX?`(just to let you know)

Comment: @Ateş GÜRAL, there is no jQuery used with the standard Calendar control. Nor with the AJAX control Toolkit. It uses the Microsoft Ajax library, not jQuery.